# Using Node 18 but 'npm install prisma' is throwing a Node version error

Tags: npm, prisma

I am getting the following error when I try 'npm install prisma'

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/path/to/project/node_modules/prisma
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- node scripts/preinstall-entry.js
npm ERR! ┌───────────────────────────────────────────┐
npm ERR! │   Prisma only supports Node.js >= 14.17   │
npm ERR! └───────────────────────────────────────────┘

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2022-11-09T20_20_18_706Z-debug-0.log
```

I am using Node 18 which I installed through nvm on Mac OS.

```
$ node --version
v18.12.1
$ nvm version
v18.12.1
```

I tried using pnpm, deleting and reinstalling nvm, and removing all other node versions, or downgrading to 16, or 18.8.0, but none of these worked.
Is this a known error? Can someone help me figure out the issue?

Comment: Did you try without using nvm? Just directly installing node v18 globally?
Also, which MacOS version are you running?

Comment: Yes, I tried removing nvm and installing node v18 from an installer. I'm running Monterey, but it was failing even before the upgrade. Also, it's not failing on my coworker's MacOS laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, there was an old `node_modules/node` directory in my home (`~`) directory. I deleted it and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove others Node version which installed by others method such as using `.pkg` or `home-brew`, because I think your OS is not using Node version that `nvm` installed.

To make sure you removed all Node versions completely from your OS, run:

```
node --version
-bash: node: command not found
```

Then reinstall Node with `nvm` again.

Hope it help!

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried this.